# Array of associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function to use but I don't know the content of this function. The only thing I know is that the function returns an array of associative arrays and the keys for the arrays. The data that the function returns come from a database. Can you help in how to read the data from this array? I am confused with the arrays. For now I am doing this:

```php
$array = myfunction($var);
if(!empty($array))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($array))
    {
        print"$row[elem1]
        $row[elem2]";
    }
}
```

I take the error:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in... I know that something is missing, but I till now I can't fix it.

Comment: Your version is so unnecessarily perplexed, I really have no idea where to start from...

Comment: Hi @Dr.Kameleon it is the same for me. I wrote what exactly I know. The part of code I know that is not correct but it is just a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like -

```
$array = myfunction($var);
foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    print"{$row['elem1']} {$row['elem2']}";
}
```

Comment: "The data that the function returns come from a database"

Comment: @webbandit it is not clear however whether or not the data has already been fetched. The asker has an array and seems to want to iterate over it.

Comment: @webbandit - OP clearly states that the function returns an array of arrays!

Comment: @nnichols no too clearly :) It states that "The data that the function returns come from a database" and uses mysql_fetch_array() function from one side and "an array of associative arrays and the keys for the arrays" from another. Not too clearly...

Comment: @webbandit - "The only thing I know is that the function returns an array of associative arrays" - seems quite clear to me.

Comment: I have written what exactly I know. I know that the function retrieves the data from a database. And the description that is given for the function is that returns an array of associative arrays? I had this query, what to use, mysql_fetch_array()  or just face it as array?

Comment: @anna - It is an array according to your documentation so just iterate over it with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 2):

If the function is returning an array then why are you using it in mysql_fetch_array. It is useless. Instead use this

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

   echo $key;
   echo '<br>';
   echo $value;
}
```

This will print the whole array.
Or a short method is

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct .. the issue is not associative arrays in php but you are not using a valid mysql resource

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php for documentation

Examples

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$row = array() ;
echo "<pre>" ;
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
            print implode (",", $row) . PHP_EOL;

    }

}
```

Or

```
$array = myfunction($var);
if(!empty($array))
{
    foreach($array as $key => $row)
    {
        if(is_array($row))
        {
            print implode (",", $row) . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
        {
            print $row . PHP_EOL ;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass Resource Identifier to mysql_fetch_array() function.

Something like:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`');
if(!empty($array)) {

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($array)) {
        print"$row[elem1]
        $row[elem2]";
 }
}
```